apk+ extension and compatibility
On an Android TV, I made some backups with CX File Explorer.
When I tried to install it on a different SmartTV, the format was not recognized and I realized about a "+" symbol after the "apk" string.
I renamed the apk+ to apk, but Android didn't recognize the installation package.
So, I installed CX File Explorer, and using it, the apk showed the proper app icon, and installation was successful.
What is the apk+ extension? Is it a new "apk" package version?
Just a "proprietary" format with a misleading extension name?
Are there more apps recognizing these packages?

Modern apps downloaded from Play Store no longer consist if one but multiple APK files. Most likely APK+ is a proprietary format that combines multiple APK files into one backup file. Therefore APK would be similar to xapk, apkm, apks... But I wasn't able to find a source that confirms my guess.

Possibly related about proprietary format: How to install xapk, apks, or multiple-apks via adb?

I prefer to keep close to the previous "standard" and therefore be compatible with a clean android. BTW, years ago CX explorer was generating compatible apk files.

The "apk+" extension is probably a special extension format used by CX File Explorer when making backups. It's not a standard Android format.
It won't work if you simply change the name to "apk" because it will lose the data added by CX File Explorer. Since CX File Explorer can install it, means it understands whatever the format is.
Therefore, CX File Explorer is the best solution to create and install these backups.
Hope this helps!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

the answer contains the same info and doubts than the original question.
